# In another computer I get System error: libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll is missing, although I used -static-libgcc and -static-libstdc++ linker options

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks, sfml

In another computer I get System error:

> libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll is missing

although I used `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++` linker options.

IDE - Code::Blocks 16.01

Compiler - GCC 4.9 (Standard MinGW 32-bit Edition)

[image: App Linker Settings]

[image: Release Linker Settings]

How to fix this?

Comment: are you creating a DLL or an executable?

Comment: I'm creating an executable file.

Comment: Problem may come from SFML DLLs. Try to copy the dll alongside the executable on the other computer and retry